# rails with globalize can't set nil value for translated field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, globalize

I am looking for some help or idea.
I have a form where i can upload an image and a text. Both are translated with "Globalize" (gem 'globalize', '~> 4.0.2')

In my model i have:
translates :content, :desc

:content : is the image url (String)
:desc  : is the description (Text)

Everything work fine but when i try to delete the image value (:content) by setting it to nil that didn't work.

The only way i found it's to delete the "translates :content, :desc" from my model but i really need this translations.

Do you know if there is a way to allow nil value with globalize? or any other idea?